# How to apply DRY approach on multiple jQuery button toggle

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

Basically I have at least 20 or more buttons and textareas like these with different class names.

```
<textarea class="widefat res_editor_exp2wid1" rows="10" cols="20" style="display: none;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('jd1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('jd1'); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($instance['jd1']); ?></textarea>
<button class="res_editor_btn_exp2wid1" type="button">Edit Content</button>
```

What I'm doing is expanding the textarea after clicking the button. By doing -

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.res_editor_btn_exp2wid1', function(){

    jQuery(".res_editor_exp2wid1").toggle("slow").click(function(){
        jQuery('.res_editor_exp2wid1').trumbowyg();
    });
});
```

Each time I have to write this jQuery which is kinda annoying and I want to make it a DRY approach. How I can achieve that ? Sorry If it sounds ridiculous I'm quite novice in this matter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could do an `each` loop instead where you loop through each div and then find each element within the div to perform your function. eg:

Assuming HTML is along the lines of:

```
<div class="foo">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
  <div class="expand_me">...</div>
</div>
```

Then your JS would be

```
jQuery('.foo').each(function() {
  $button = $(this).find('button');
  $div = $(this).find('.expand_me');
  // do something to the button + div
});
```

2) You could create a function that you call for each of the 20 things that need to have this behavior:

```
var clickable = function(unique_code) {
  jQuery(document).on('click', '.res_editor_btn_'+unique_code, function(){
    jQuery(".res_editor_"+unique_code).toggle("slow").click(function(){
      jQuery('.res_editor_'+unique_code).trumbowyg();
    });
  });
};
```

Then for each of the 20 times you need to do this:

```
clickable('exp2wid1');
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, I'll try to implement this and get back to you